# Local sql server express attachment issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a data connection to a .mdf file on the network of the form: User Instance on local SQL Server Express

When computer restart the data connection is gone (red x) in the server explorer in VS.

If I refresh in VS server explorer my application will connect to the .mdf file.

I need some code or setting in my application that refresh the data connection everytime the application starts.

Comment: You don't connect directly to an mdf file, you connect to the server. This is all a little vague, but it sounds like your service isn't set to start when the Computer does.

Comment: @Larnu can I do this from the application or do I need to set this option manually on every computer that will use the application?

Comment: I'm not much of an application developer I'm afraid, but *normally* (from my small experience) it's a application setting you apply at build; or for a website the setting can be done for each website.